# superscripts on customized unit in siunitx

Tags: siunitx, subscripts, superscripts

I want to add subscripts to some units and so far the solution I found is to define my own unit, for instance:

```
 \DeclareSIUnit{\Lmedia}{\text{$\textup{L}_{\textup{media}}$}}
```

However, when I use this with \SI the superscript is too far away. Here's a MWE of what I mean:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\Lmedia}{%
    \text{$\textup{L}_{\textup{media}}$}%
}

\begin{document}

\SI{1}{\mol\per\milli\Lmedia}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this? or alternatively, is there a better way to include my own subscripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\Lmedia}{\text{L}_{\text{media}}}%
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\mol\per\milli\Lmedia}
\end{document}
```

[image]